# How to skip the first activity after press the home button?(Android)

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

(Android)
The first activity is SplashActivity.

I want to skip the first activity when I do like this :
Open the app -> SplashActivity -> SecondActivity-> press home button -> press the app icon -> SecondActivity

Is this possible? How?

```
SOLVED

android:launchMode shoud be "standard"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to do anything when you press the home button and then launch the app again, the SecondActivity will be shown. If you want to when press the back button then the app exists then call finish() in SplashActivity when you start SecondActivity.

Comment: That will cause the back button to not return to SplashActivity, but OP wants the app to resume where it left off at SecondActivity when the user returns to it.

Comment: @Edward Falk you are absolutely right. I am not thinking when answer this question. This only help if the app is killed by the OS and the OS recreated the stack when the app is launched again. Actually, he does not have to do anything and when he start again the second screen will be shown.

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" does not work, but android:launchMode="standard" works

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to override the `onPause()` method of SecondActivity to store some marker indicating that the app reached that activity, and then have the `onResume()` method of SplashActivity start SecondActivity immediately if that state is found.

See the Activity documentation for more information on the activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle.

A better design might be to have SecondActivity start initially, and then start SplashActivity on top of itself. That way, if it found the state marker from the previous run, it would never have to start SplashActivity at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to accomplish this.  Personally I'd avoid using a splash activity at all..  they are bloated for nothing.  A toast accomplishes the same thing, and it can be dismissed when your activity is done it's load.. 
I have pictures and text on my toast, so it really looks like a splash..

What you want to do is test if the second activity is in a paused state when you start your first activity, and then if it is paused, you want to finish(); the first activity.

Though I'm no pro I think you'll have to store something in the onpause call of the second app, and clear it in the onstop method..

Again all this can be handled smoother if you just present a toast in the on create of a single activity.  open_app => on_create => toast => hide_toast when load is done =>  press home => press app icon => no_on_create => no toast => press back button => app closes => press icon => goto_10

NOTE:  when you press the back button all bets are off.  the app is unloaded from memory, so if your splash is to hide loading (the only reason to ever have a splash), then you'll have to show the splash again, because your app has to load again.

If you are using the splash as an ad' and don't want to show it too often; then I suggest using SharedPreferences and storing the last time the splash was displayed, or the last time the app was paused, and say if (pause_seconds + 120 < now_seconds) display_splash()

Comment: actually if you go with the flag, then store it during the onPause and clear it during the onResume.